# How to get around a "withdrawal address format is wrong" error?

Tags: address

I would like to transfer some ADA from a binanceus.com account to a Coinbase Pro account.

To do this, I get a receive address from the Coinbase Pro web site, which I copy-paste as-is to the appropriate blank in the binanceus.com site's funds transfer form.  After I initiate the transfer, it fails immediately with an error of the form:

> addr1vyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> The withdrawal address format is wrong. Please check the withdrawal address length and character content and try again

(Though I have redacted with X's most of the receive address in the listing above, I have preserved the original number of characters, namely 58.)

I have attempted this multiple times, with new receive addresses from the Coinbase Pro site, with pretty much the same results.  (FWIW, all these other addresses have had the same length as the one shown above, and they all have begun with the `addr` prefix.)

I submitted a ticket to binanceus.com's customer support several days ago, but have received no answer (other than an automatic "we're really busy" one).

---

**Qs:** Is there some alternative format I could use for such an address?  If so, are there tools I could use to safely convert a specific address to this alternative format?  Alternatively, where can I find a description of the algorithm to convert from one format to another, so that I can implement the conversion myself?

Answer (score 3):

It may be that your copy/paste is carrying across more characters than you expect. It may contain a trailing whitespace or non-visible character (e.g. cr or newline).

On Windows, I eliminate this possibility by pasting to notepad and then copying from notepad to the destination.

Try with a small transaction first to verify the process and correct destination address.